# Classic ASP - Getting xml node's values from ResponseText

Tags: xml, web-services, xpath, asp-classic, nodes

From *Classic ASP*, how to get the particular *xml node's* values from the `ResponseText` which is in `xml` format returned as `string` ?

Code:

```
<%
        If Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD") = "POST" Then
            Dim objRequest, objXMLDoc, objXmlNode
            Dim strRet, strError, strNome
            Dim strName
            envName= Request.Form("text1")
            Set objRequest = Server.createobject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
            With objRequest
            .open "GET", "http://dev.xxx.com/Testservice/Services/MyService.asmx/Load?code=" & envName, False
            .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
            .setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", "http://dev.xxx.com/Testservice/Services/MyService.asmx/Load"
            .send
            End With
            Set objXMLDoc = Server.createobject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
            objXmlDoc.async = false

            Response.Write(objRequest.ResponseText)
        End If
%>
```

I am getting the `objRequest.ResponseText` as string in xml format which is as following:

```
<string xmlns="http://xxx.yyy.com/">
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?> 
  <Parent xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
     <Textbox> 
         <Id>001</Id> 
         <Name>Name1</Name> 
      </Textbox> 
      <Textbox> 
        <Id>002</Id> 
        <Name>Name2</Name> 
      </Textbox> 
      <Textbox> 
        <Id>003</Id> 
        <Name>Name3</Name> 
      </Textbox> 
      <Textbox> 
        <Id>004</Id> 
        <Name>Name4</Name> 
      </Textbox> 
      <Textbox> 
        <Id>005</Id> 
        <Name>Name5</Name> 
      </Textbox> 
      <Textbox> 
         <Id>006</Id> 
         <Name>Name6</Name> 
      </Textbox> 
   </Parent>
</string>
```

Now, I need to get the ***Name*** `node` values. That is, I need to bind the name values in the dropdown in asp page. Values are `Name1, Name2, Name3, Name4, Name5, Name6`.

I tried the following code to retreive the ***name*** `node` values

```
Response.Write(objXmlDoc.selectSingleNode("//Textbox/Name"))
```

but, I am not able to retreive the ***name*** `node` values. Guide me to solve this. Thanks.

Comment: I've never seen the `<xml>` node _within_ another before. In fact, even when the `<xml>` node is listed first, I have trouble parsing XML docs if there's so much as a single space or blank line before it.

Comment: Actual `xml` I got doesn't have single space or blank line. To clearly present, I formatted `xml` code here. Any ideas on how to get the values of `Name` node ?. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your XML has *default namespace* declared at the root level :

```
xmlns="http://xxx.yyy.com/"
```

This makes all elements without explicit prefix and without more local-scoped default namespace considered in the root's default namespace. To access element in namespace you need to define a prefix, map it to the namespace uri, and use that prefix in your XPath accordingly, for example :

```
objXMLDoc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:d='http://xxx.yyy.com/'"

Response.Write(objXmlDoc.selectSingleNode("//d:Textbox/d:Name").text)
```

side note: AFAIK, processing instructions like `<?xml?>` is not allowed in a well-formed XML except at the very beginning of the XML.

Comment: I tried your code..I am getting the error message as `Response object error 'ASP 0185 : 80020003' 

Missing Default Property 

/SampleAsp.asp, line 0 

A default property was not found for the object.`

Comment: `Response.Write(objXmlDoc.selectSingleNode("//d:Textbox/d:Name").text)`

Comment: @SearchAndResQ, I added `.text`, but now I am getting the error message as `Microsoft VBScript runtime  error '800a01a8' 

Object required: '[object]' 

/SampleAsp.asp, line 34 
`. In the error message, the _line 34_ is `Response.Write(objXmlDoc.selectSingleNode("//d:Textbox/d:Name").text)`

Comment: @JohnStephen [please do not repost the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31643953/getting-xml-nodes-values-from-responsetext-in-classic-asp). check if the xml is loaded at all, use `objXmlDoc.parseerror.reason` to see if there are any errors after the `load` of the xml

Comment: @JohnStephen If it is really the case that you got error due to `<?xml ?>` tag, maybe you want to replace the problematic `<?xml ?>`  first, then try to continue using this approach -instead of resorting all the way to regex, as in your new question-

Comment: @har07, Can you guide me to replace xml in `objRequest.ResponseText` and providing the solution. I am also interested in fixing the issue in `xml` instead of going to `regex` but too much time taking for this. Help me. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnStephen first, make sure that's the error. Have you tried to see the error message as suggested by @SearchAndResQ? Then you can try using simple `string.replace()` to remove the `<?xml?>`

Comment: @har07, I had tried with the sample xml and I can able to retreive those name values. In the sample xml I don't use the `<string xmlns="http://xxx.yyy.com/">`. Now i need to replace the `<string xmlns="http://xxx.yyy.com/">` with `empty` and also at the bottom `</string>` with `empty` in `responseText`. Guide me to replace this. Thanks.
 
 `